# Given N, for consecutive numbers from 1 to N create a recursive C# method to print out all possible '+' and '-' combinations that result in X

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, coin-change

I'm dealing with the following assignment, and as I'm not very familiar with recursion I'm at a loss. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone with more experience could point me in the right direction.

The assignment reads as follows:
Write a console application that determines all combinations of '+' and '-' operators which can be put between natural numbers ranging from 1 to a given N >=2, so that the result of the expression is a given X number. If there is no possible combination, the application will output 'N/A'.

Ex:
For inputs:
6 //N
3 //X

The console will read:
`1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3`
`1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3`
`1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3`

Given the circumstances of the assignment, I'm not allowed to use any other directive than 'System'. I've found several versions of this 'Coin Change' problem, but mostly in C++ or Python and also quite different than my current assignment. I'm not asking anyone to do my assignment for me, I'm simply looking for some valid pointers so I know where to start.

Comment: This is just a permutation problem. You can do it with recursion or stacks or queues, by just iterating through each operator (only 2) and recursing or stacking next levels until your reach N, then validated then result

Comment: Can you iterate through the numbers building a sum ("1+2+3")? Can you change that to include "-" ("1+2+3", "1+2-3", "1-2+3", "1-2-3")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample should help you. You can adapt this recursion to your needs, since it only counts number of such combinations.

Take into account that this approach is quite slow, you can find some DP solutions that are much faster.

```
    private static int Search(int start, int end, int cur, int searched)
    {
        if (start > end)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(cur == searched);
        }

        return Search(start + 1, end, cur + start, searched) + Search(start + 1, end, cur - start, searched);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = Search(2, 6, 1, 3);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this clear and concise sample. Luckily, time complexity is not a problem as the assignment's purpose is to practice recursion.

Comment: How would the DP approach look like? I have trouble figuring it out because all numbers have to be used and so I cannot see potential equivalent classes.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a function (let's call it f) that takes 5 parameters: The current number, the end number (N), the desidered result (X), the formula so far and the result of the formula so far.

In the function you first test if the current number is the end number. If it is, then test if the result of the formula is the desired number. If it is, print the formula.

If you're not at the end yet, then call the function itself twice. Once where you add the next number and once where you subtract it.

The first call to the function would be
f(1, 6, 3, "1", 1). It would then call itself twice with
f(2, 6, 3, "1 + 2", 3) and
f(2, 6, 3, "1 - 2", -1)
Then it would continue like that until it reaches the calls with 6 numbers in the formula where it would check if the result is 3.

Hope that helps you get started.

Answer (score -1):

This answer strives to be the pinnacle in the art of helping without helping.
Which is what was asked for.

So here, the complete albeit a bit obfuscated solution in a language, you might have never heard of. But if you think about what you see long enough, you might get an idea how to solve this in C#.

```
data Expr = Lit Integer | Add | Sub deriving(Show)

compute :: [Expr] -> Integer -> Integer
compute [] value = value
compute (Add : Lit x : rest) value = compute rest (value + x)
compute (Sub : Lit x : rest) value = compute rest (value - x)
compute (Lit x1 : Add : Lit x2 : rest) value = compute rest (value + x1 + x2)
compute (Lit x1 : Sub : Lit x2 : rest) value = compute rest (value + x1 - x2)
compute [Lit x] _  = x


solve :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Expr] -> [[Expr]] -> [[Expr]]
solve goal [] current found
    | goal == compute current 0 = current : found
    | otherwise = found
solve goal (n:ns) current found =
    solve goal ns (current ++ [Add, Lit n]) [] 
        ++  solve goal ns (current ++ [Sub, Lit n]) []

prettyFormula :: [Expr] -> String
prettyFormula f =
    concat $ fmap (\xp -> case xp of 
                            Lit n -> show n
                            Add -> "+"
                            Sub -> "-") f
```

With that loaded and with `fmap prettyFormula (solve 3 [2..6] [Lit 1] [])` in the REPL, you get your result:

> `["1+2+3-4-5+6","1+2-3+4+5-6","1-2-3-4+5+6"]`